# Adding a blank row at midnight to separate data for next day

Tags: google-apps-script

I have multiple worksheets with data that is inserted during the day and at midnight I want to add a blank row from the last row that was filled with data, is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: How is data entered during the day? Even if you add a blank row at midnight, how will you make sure data for next day is not entered in that added blank row?

Comment: Through a flutter app, Google Apps script gets data from there and then just appends to the last row available in a given worksheet, works clean. However, I guess I'd just fill the row with some color and paste "/" values into them to mark the end of the day, so the script would recognize the row isn't blank. It doesn't need to be blank, it just needs to mark end of the day and separate it for the next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

Install a time-driven trigger that fires a function which appends a row with a blank space at column `A` (so that the row is not treated as empty by your day script).

**Step 1. Function to append row**:

You can use [Sheet.appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) for this:

```
function appendBlankRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet_names = ["SHEET_1", "SHEET_2"]; // Change according to your preferences
  sheet_names.forEach(sheet_name => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
    sheet.appendRow([" "]);
  });
}
```

`sheet_names` is an array with the names of the sheets to which you want to append the blank row. If that's the case for all the sheets in your spreadsheet, consider using [Spreadsheet.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) instead.

**Step 2. Install midnight trigger**:

You can do this manually (following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)), or programmatically, by running this function once:

```
function installMidnightTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("appendBlankRow")
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(0)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I add a line if theres not one below the last line of data when I want to go to the bottom of a page.

```
function goToBottom() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let lr=sh.getLastRow();
  let mr=sh.getMaxRows();
  if(lr==mr) {
    sh.insertRowAfter(mr);
  }
  sh.getRange(lr + 1, 1).activate();
}
```

Comment: It may not be elegant but I think that's in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I found similar solution already before asking and I guess I can tweak it to get what I want, but am still wondering if there's a simple way of doing it at a predefined time (midnight) and even if there are rows left.

Comment: You might have been more clear about what you wanted and perhaps you should have included  what you had already found in your question thus saving  the time of other volunteers from responding unnecessarily to your question.